# Read in a file by setting name at command line

Tags: c

What is the best approach to reading in a text file word by word in C but defining the filename as a command line variable?

I'd like to define the file name as a parameter and then read it line by line. Currently it is hardcoded as a string within the file.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    char* filename = "c:\\temp\\test.txt";
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL)
        char* text = str;
        char* key = "pangram";
        char* cipherText = Encipher(text, key, '-');
        char* plainText = Decipher(cipherText, key);
        printf("\nkey = %s",key );
        printf("\nPlain text = %s",plainText );
        printf("\nEncipher = %s",cipherText );
        printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There must be thousands of decent C beginners books which includes information on how to read input from files. And probably tens of thousands of tutorials all over the Internet. Don't try to come up with something fancy, just something that can read *space delimited strings*, and if there's some other requirement that it doesn't fulfill then post that (as an [mcve]) and include the requirements you have problems with.

Comment: "reading in a text file word by word" --> Try `char word[100];  while (scanf("%99s", word) == 1) { use word  somehow; }`.  Otherwise provide more application information.

Comment: what has this code in common with the question? Do not put random code from internet.

Comment: Question updated with more particulars

Comment: Use command-line arguments .. `int main(int argc, char **argv) {...}` and call your exe as `program.exe test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the commandline arguments prepared by the C runtime environment:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // the rest of your program...

    return 0;
}
```